# In Flex, components are not dispatching keyDown event when it's used in PopupWrapper

Tags: apache-flex, events, flex4

I'm using a component in a cairngorm PopupWrapper. I want to listen to the KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWn event on the component but it doesn't seem to be dispatching it. Is it because it's in PopupWrapper? Is there anyway I can get it to dispatch the event?

```
<fx:Declaration>
    <cairngorm:PopupWrapper>
        <mx:UIComponent keyDown="keyDownHandler()" />
    </cairngorm:PopupWrapper>
</fx:Declaration>
```

Comment: May it be that your component has no focus?

Comment: Maybe the component does not, or does not have any children, which dispatch the keyDown event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

PopupWrapper only adds FocusManager to the component if it implements IFocusManagerContainer. My component was extending SkinnableComponent thus did not receive any focus.  So I made my component extend from SkinnableContainer instead. I also had to manually set focus to my component on "opened" event. Now keyDown is dispatched as expected.